# How to handle Button click event from Table view to create Hyperlink

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I have two columns, one is *Button*  which is the one that I click and the other is *Hyperlink* which should update after the *Link created* Button action event. I was try with method

```
  Param item = (Param) getTableRow().getItem();
                item.setHyperlink("Link is created");
```

But it doesn't work.

**Please help me how to create hyperlink into *Hyperlink* column after the Button same row action event. It look like as below** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCrDe.png)

//Here is Class Controller

```
public class SampleController {

@FXML
private TableColumn<Param, Hyperlink> hyperlinkcol;

@FXML
private TableView<Param> table;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Param, String> buttoncol;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Param, String> descriptioncol;
public static ObservableList<Param> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    hyperlinkcol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("hyperlink"));
    buttoncol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("hyperlink"));
    descriptioncol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Description"));
    buttoncol.setCellFactory(new Buttoncell());
    data.add(new Param("David"));
    data.add(new Param("Marry"));
    table.setItems(data);
} }
```

//Here is Class Param

```
public class Param {
private String Description;
private Hyperlink hyperlink;
public Param(String description) {
    super();
    Description = description;

}
public String getDescription() {
    return Description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    Description = description;
}
public Hyperlink getHyperlink() {
    return hyperlink;
}
public void setHyperlink(String hyperlink) {
    this.hyperlink = new Hyperlink(hyperlink);
}
}
```

// Here is Class Buttoncell

```
 public class Buttoncell implements Callback<TableColumn<Param, String>, 
TableCell<Param, String>> {

@Override
public TableCell<Param, String> call(TableColumn<Param, String> arg) {

    TableCell<Param, String> cell = new TableCell<Param, String>() {

        private final Button button;

        {
            button = new Button();
            button.setOnAction(evt -> {
                Param item = (Param) getTableRow().getItem();
                item.setHyperlink("Link is created");
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            if (empty) {

                setGraphic(null);
            } else {

                if (item != null && !item.isEmpty()) {

                    button.setText("Click");
                } else {
                    button.setText("Link created");
                }
                setGraphic(button);
            }
        }
    };
    return cell;
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code demos what you are asking. This code creates the `Button's` `cellFactory` in the `Controller`.  **New Updates to the `Controller` class and the `Param` class!**

> Full Code:

**Main Class**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication215 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.util.Callback;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable
{

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Param, String> hyperlinkcol, descriptioncol, buttoncol;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Param> table;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        // TODO

        descriptioncol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("description"));
        hyperlinkcol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("hyperlink"));

        Callback<TableColumn<Param, String>, TableCell<Param, String>> cellFactory0
                = (final TableColumn<Param, String> entry) -> {
                    final TableCell<Param, String> cell = new TableCell<Param, String>()
            {

                Hyperlink hyperlink = new Hyperlink();

                @Override
                public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
                {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                        setText(null);
                    }
                    else {
                        Param tempParam = table.getItems().get(getIndex());
                        if (tempParam.isBtnState()) {
                            System.out.println("set hyperlink");
                            hyperlink.setText(item);
                            hyperlink.setOnAction((event) -> {
                                System.out.println("Go to URL");
                            });
                            setGraphic(hyperlink);
                            setText(null);
                        }
                        else {
                            hyperlink.setText("");
                            setGraphic(null);
                            setText(null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
                    return cell;
                };
        hyperlinkcol.setCellFactory(cellFactory0);

        Callback<TableColumn<Param, String>, TableCell<Param, String>> cellFactory
                = (TableColumn<Param, String> param) -> {
                    final TableCell<Param, String> cell = new TableCell<Param, String>()
            {
                final Button btn = new Button();

                @Override
                public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
                {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                        setText(null);
                    }
                    else {
                        int currentIndex = getIndex();
                        System.out.println("current index: " + currentIndex);
                        Param param = table.getItems().get(currentIndex);
                        btn.setText(param.getButtonText());

                        btn.setOnAction(event -> {
                            param.setBtnState(true);
                            param.setButtonText(param.getHyperlink());
                            table.getItems().set(currentIndex, param);
                        });
                        setText(null);
                        setGraphic(btn);

                    }
                }
            };

                    return cell;
                };

        buttoncol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);

        ObservableList<Param> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        data.add(new Param("description 1", "www.google.com", false, "Button 1"));
        data.add(new Param("description 2", "www.facebook.com", false, "Button 2"));
        data.add(new Param("description 3", "www.yahoo.com", false, "Button 3"));
        data.add(new Param("description 4", "www.amazon.com", false, "Button 4"));

        table.setItems(data);
    }

}
```

**FXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication215.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="table" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="buttoncol" prefWidth="130.0" text="Button" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="hyperlinkcol" prefWidth="252.0" text="Link" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="descriptioncol" prefWidth="217.0" text="Description" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

**Param Class**

```
/**
 *
 * @author sedri
 */
public class Param
{

    private String buttonText;
    private boolean btnState;
    private String hyperlink;
    private String description;

    public Param(String description, String hyperlink, boolean btnState, String buttonText)
    {
        this.hyperlink = hyperlink;
        this.description = description;
        this.btnState = btnState;
        this.buttonText = buttonText;
    }

    public String getButtonText()
    {
        return buttonText;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public void setButtonText(String buttonText)
    {
        this.buttonText = buttonText;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getHyperlink()
    {
        return hyperlink;
    }

    public void setHyperlink(String hyperlink)
    {
        this.hyperlink = hyperlink;
    }

    public boolean isBtnState()
    {
        return btnState;
    }

    public void setBtnState(boolean btnState)
    {
        this.btnState = btnState;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Sedrich .Thank you for your answer I'm trying with ur code But can you share me your Class Param ? Is there any modification from My Class Param ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I posted it.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: @ Sedrich Maybe you've misunderstood. Lets see on ur image  you posted. on the 1st row , I want www.google.com Hyperlink (Not String) display after button same row clicked Other below links are not display. The 2nd row  I want www.facbook.com Hyperlink (Not String) display after button same row clicked Other below links are not display ... It looks like i asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815571/handle-button-click-event-from-table-view/50818847?noredirect=1#comment88668611_50818847

Comment: I assumed you could do that logic with the code given.

Comment: I updated the answer. It should do what you need now.

Comment: I don't know what you are saying?

Comment: Sorry But a bit of issue That i sorted Description Column on table view .The Button column is non following change :(

Comment: Technically, the `Button's` action sorts but I see what you mean.

Comment: Could you edit the code above ? i  set Text for button at Update item But it cant be ran

Comment: It is not easy to modify And is challenge to me and you Because  btn.setOnAction(event  should be long to new button method Its should not be long to update item method